# Do I have to write the independent variable always?

Tags: functions

I'm not used to using Mathematica. Please help me.

What I want to do is similar to the following:

`U` and `V` are unknown function of `z`. `k` and `l` are constants.
Define `A = U*k+V*l` and differentiate `A` by `z`.

To do above, I did `A[z]=U[z]*k+V[z]*l; D[A[z],z]`. But it's very annoying to write `[z]` all the times!

Is there any good method to write just `U`, `V`, `A`, `U'`, `A'` etc. instead of `U[z]`, `V[z]`,  `A[z]`, `U'[z]`, `A'[z]` etc.? (But `k` and `l` must not regarded as `k[z]` and `l[z]`).

Comment: There might be workarounds, but I suggest you keep writing the [z] because then the code is easier to understand. When you have multiple variables, you can define a vector function like U[Z] with Z={x,y} or Z=Sequence[x,y].

Comment: @banone Thank you!!!